# Как удалить кэш страницы?

Tags: php, кэширование

Пытаюсь запилить простенькую авторизацию через cookie, и почти уже все сделал, но в самом конце сталкиваюсь с проблемой: при нажатии кнопки выхода пользователя отправляет на php скрипт, который просто удаляет данные куки из браузера, но если пользователь пользователь пытается вернутся на предыдущую страницу, она, видимо, загружается из кэша и до перезагрузки выглядит так, как-будто пользователь все еще залогинен.

Как это можно пофиксить?

Собственно логин проверяю таким образом. В начале каждой страницы тыкаю такую проверку

```
require_once('config/config.php');
checkLogin($_COOKIE["LoginData"]);
```

А вот и сама checkLogin

```
function checkLogin($data){
global $sqlconnection;

$check = "/[0-9]\:[a-z0-9]/";
if (preg_match($check, $data)) {
    $login = explode(":", $data);
    $result = mysqli_query($sqlconnection, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '".$login[0]."'");
    $user_data = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    mysqli_free_result($result);

    if($user_data["astring"] != $login[1]){
        away();
    }
}else {
    away();
}

function away(){
   header("location: register.html");
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> Как пофиксить выдачу страниц из кеша?

как вариант — выключить его:

```
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); 
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
```

Answer (score 0):

Надо смотреть ваш код. Скорей всего у вас после авторизации, куки заново присваиваются (обновляются) при каждой загрузке страницы. И поэтому когда возвращаешься назад, браузер снова загружает в куки данные авторизации. Так не должно быть, надо смотреть ваш код.

Answer (score 0):

Авторизацию лучше делать через сессии.

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['LoginData'] = 'Логин юзверя';
```

И проверка, соответственно:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['LoginData'])){
    echo 'Чувак, ты зарегин под логином '.$_SESSION['LoginData'];
}
```

А разлогинить его можно так:

```
if(isset($_POST['logout'])){
    unset('$_SESSION['LoginData']');
    echo 'Чувак, мы тебя потеряли...';
}
```